# How can I copy multiple char* strings into one using strcpy_s()?

Tags: c++, c-strings, strcpy, strcat

Using the `strcpy_s()` function I want to collate the first three strings into the final one to print my full name. This is what I have and it doesn't work as I'm using `char*` strings and not `std::string`s.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str_first[] = "Nerf_";
    char str_middle[] = " Herder";
    char str_last[] = "42";

    char str_fullName[35];

    strcpy_s(str_fullName, (str_first + str_middle + str_last).c_str());
    cout << str_fullName;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's going to be much simpler to use something other than  `strcpy_s`. But perhaps the whole point of your task is that your teacher/instructor wants you to learn how to use only `strcpy_s` and do some pointer arithmetic and logic. I suspect that's the case here. If so, you will need to do a lot more work than that. You will have to `strcpy_s` each part, in turn, and figure out ***exactly where*** each `strcpy_s` should go. Good luck, and welcome to C++. As far as suggestions go, [you should go and discuss this with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Make sure the output buffer is large enough. Then, if you can use it, read some [good documentation for `strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat). If you're stuck with `strcpy` keep a pointer to where the null terminator is after each append and keep calling `strcpy` with a pointer to the location of the null and the next string to append.

Comment: Ah pointers, my old friend.... Yes, my task is to specifically use strcpy, I found pointers when initially learning C++ and have overlooked them ever since. I'll have a look at it agin using pointers, thanks :)

Comment: Or `snprintf(str_fullName, sizeof str_fullName, "%s%s%s", str_first,  str_middle,  str_last);` and let the compiler form optimal code.  Suppose it is too C-ish for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use both `strcat` and `strcpy`

See code comments for more info.

```
// disable SDL warnings in Visual studio
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // TODO: insert checking code,
    // to make sure destination can hold all characters + one termination.

    char str_first[] = "Nerf_";
    char str_middle[] = " Herder";
    char str_last[] = "42";

    char str_fullName[35];

    // copy first string because we need null terminated destination
    strcpy(str_fullName, str_first);

    // append the rest, string is auto null terminated.
    strcat(str_fullName, str_middle);
    strcat(str_fullName, str_last);

    cout << str_fullName;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks so much for the comments too, they really helped me actually understand what I was doing wrong. :)

Comment: @Nerf_Herder42 Using multiple `strcpy(_s)` calls with pointer arithmetic, like [Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61603157/65863) shows, is more efficient then using `strcpy` and multiple `strcat` calls. `strcat` has to re-scan the target buffer each time to figure out where it needs to insert to. With just `strcpy(_s)` alone, you can avoid that redundant memory scanning.

Answer (score 2):

This should be close to what you're looking for, strictly using [`strcpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to concatenate strings together:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str_first[] = "Nerf_";
    char str_middle[] = " Herder";
    char str_last[] = "42";

    char str_fullName[35];

    int index = strcpy_s(str_fullName, sizeof str_fullName, str_first);
    index += strcpy_s(str_fullName + index, sizeof str_fullName - index, str_middle);
    index += strcpy_s(str_fullName + index, sizeof str_fullName - index, str_last);
    cout << str_fullName;
}
```

The `index` variable serves a couple of purposes: (1) to provide a new index into the output `str_fullName` string as the string is built, and (2) subtracted from `sizeof str_fullName`, it "adjusts" the available buffer size as the string is built.

Caveats are that you should add overflow checking via the output from [`strcpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), and (as noted by others) there are better patterns to follow for doing this, but probably as an academic exercise there's something good to be learned here.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken the function `strcpy_s` expects three arguments. So either supply one more argument to the function call or use instead the function `strcpy`.

And there is no need to use the standard class std::string to perform the task.

The code can look the following way

```
strcpy( str_fullName, str_first );
strcat( str_fullName, str_middle );
strcat( str_fullName, str_last );
```

Or you could use `strcpy_s` and `strcat_s` provided that you will specify the correct number of arguments.

Pay attention to that you need to include the header

```
#include <cstring>
```